# Django admin: How to populate a new object from GET variables?

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django's admin, I've seen how I can set the fields of an 'add object' form using GET variables (e.g. `/admin/app/model/add?title=lol` sets the 'Title' field to 'lol').

However, I want to be able to do something along the lines of `/admin/app/model/add?key=18` and load default data for my fields from an instance of another model. Ideally, I'd also like to be able to do some processing on the values that I populate the form with. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. Thankfully, Django allows you to replace a `request`'s `GET` dict (which it uses to pre-populate the admin form). The following worked for me:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...

    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        source_id = request.GET.get('source', None)
        if source_id is not None:
            source = FeedPost.objects.get(id=source_id)
            # any extra processing can go here...
            g = request.GET.copy()
            g.update({
                'title': source.title,
                'contents': source.description + u"... \n\n[" + source.url + "]",
            })
            request.GET = g

        return super(ArticleAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
```

This way, I obtain the `source` object from a [URL parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), do what I want with them, and pre-populate the form.

Comment: This is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You can override method `add_view` of `ModelAdmin` instance. Add getting an object there, set object's `pk` to `None` and provide that object as an `instance` to the form. Object with `pk == None` will be always inserted as a new object in the database on form's `save()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I played around with add_view; however, the super method returns a rendered form, and I don't know how to populate it beforehand.

Comment: Don't use super method yet. Just change [form creation](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L936) so it could get and use an object as `initial`. You can also override `get_form` and create a form class with correct `instance` built-in, it will be more DRY but also more complicated code.